# Maven dependencies wrong Jersey class chosen at runtime

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I have a Java Servlet project with Maven and Tomcat which contains the following two dependencies (amongst many others):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-serviceruntime</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`jersey-server` includes `javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1`, and `azure-serviceruntime` includes `jersey-core:1.13` which both contain the class `Application` in the package `javax.ws.rs.core`.

Searching the `Application` type in Eclipse shows the following (to clarify):
[image: The two Application classes]

The problem is that at runtime the wrong `Application` class is used which results in the following error when starting Tomcat:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

For every servlet.

I tried excluding `jersey-core` from the `azure-serviceruntime` but then the servlets don't seem to load at all. I also tried to add `javax.ws.rs-api` as a direct dependency but that also didn't work. The most unexplainable part is that it does work on Windows but not on Linux...
I also tried relocating classes/packages with maven shade but without any success.

How can I tell Java to use the latest `Application` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. I looked further into the fact that it works on Windows and not Linux, the difference is that on Windows I use the OracleJDK and on Linux the openJDK.

So I used OracleJDK for my project on Linux and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use [dependency exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to exclude *jersey-core:1.13* from the azure-serviceruntime dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-serviceruntime</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Azure uses the jersey-core from com.sun.jersey though. But I already tried excluding that one and then the servlets don't seem to load (I can't reach them through HTTP anymore), but I do not really know why.